# PhoneGap App - Free App and Paid App with Same Database

Tags: android, cordova, storage, shared

I have developed 2 mobile apps using PhoneGap. One is a free ad supported version with slightly limited features and the other is the full version without ads. My app saves data in both localStorage key pairs and the WebSQL open database.

Ideally I would like both apps to share the same storage as currently each app has it's own database in their respective install paths. I need this so if someone has used my free app for a few weeks and saved a lot of data they can upgrade to the full version and their data will be preserved.

Another solution would be to have an Import / Export feature, which eventually I would like to implement anyway to allow users to backup their data or even transfer to a new phone. However, for the sheer convenience of having both apps use the same database I would much prefer to get that working first.

**App Info:**

Storage: localStorage Key Pairs and WebSQL (openDatabase();)

Language: HTML, CSS, JavaScript

Platform: Android Honeycomb+

Database: 2 Tables, 'temp' and 'shifts' consisting of id (INT), startTime (DATETIME), stopTime (DATETIME), shiftTime (FLOAT).

I'm not looking for full code examples of how to do this, I just need some advice on which methods are possible and where to start with implementing them. I appreciate your time, so thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
Mitchell Ransom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in android platform every app has it own isolated storage in `/data/data/packagename` that only app itself could access there, in your case one solution is package both free and paid app as same so android install paid app on free app(it will keep user data including your data bases) second solution is save your database at sdcard(not recommended) and third one  as you point out is import/export functionality.

Comment: When you say install the paid app on the free app, could you explain that a bit more? I didn't think it was possible but for sure that sounds like the best way to solve my problem. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: every app has it's own package line com.example.program name when you have one apk installed with com.example.program an then try to install another package with same package name android will replace first program with second one and all user dada will be untouch , problom with this approach is google play because you cant have two identical package name in google play system .

Comment: Ahh then I wont be able to use this approach as I am only using Google Play to distribute my app. Back to the drawing board I go! If you have any advice for me on creating the import and export functionality through JavaScript and PhoneGap that would be awesome. Thanks for your help already.

Comment: one way is to using cloud , backup your data bases in your server.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll give it a go, cloud does tie into a future upgrade I was considering.